# parsing error invoking static function on object instance?

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods

I'm wondering if the following code should be considered valid c++, gcc and clang both choke on it while Microsoft and the embedded compiler (green hills) our project uses seem to parse this without problems. This line of code gives gcc and clang trouble:

```
foo().Bar<int>();
```

It appears gcc thinks the < is a less than operator instead of specifying a template argument. If Bar is changed to not be a template function gcc accepts it.

```
class Test1
{
public:
   template<typename U>
   static void Bar() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Test2
{
public:
   Test2()
   {
      foo().Bar<int>();
   }
   Test1 foo() { return t; }
   Test1 t;
};

int main()
{
   Test2<int> t;
}
```

From my research calling a static member function on an object instance is valid c++. So what are you thoughts? Here is gcc's error:

```
Error.cpp: In constructor ‘Test2<T>::Test2()’:
Error.cpp:14:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
       foo().Bar<int>();
                 ^
Error.cpp:14:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
```

Comment: What compile errors do you get?

Comment: I edited the post to include gcc's error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
foo().template Bar<int>();
```

Comment: Thanks! I have not come across this syntax before.In case anyone is interested I ran across this issue (in more complex code) while using [Lightweight Generic C++ Callbacks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136799/Lightweight-Generic-C-Callbacks-or-Yet-Another-Del).

Answer (score 0):

(Adding to @Dieter answer)

Otherwise you have to use a temporary:

```
  Test1 tt = foo();
  tt.Bar<int>();
```

(in this case you could have simply used `t` instead of `tt`, but that was not the point, of course).

Comment: This does fix the example code (I tested it). However, it is not possible to do this in the original (more complex code) where the problem presented. Thanks.